# Else não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá. Tenho um website no qual inseri o recaptcha do google. O captcha funciona corretamente, porém, não consigo fazer exibir um erro caso a mensagem seja enviada. A notificação de "mensagem enviada com sucesso" é exibida normalmente, mas a notificação de "mensagem NÃO enviada" não aparece de jeito nenhum. Porém, o resto funciona normalmente, a mensagem só é enviada se o captcha for preenchido. O único problema é a notificação de não enviada.

Segue o código

```
                    <div class="row">
                    <!--=== Contact Form ===-->
                    <form id="contact-form" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" method="post" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="contact-name">Nome</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="contact-name" name="nome" placeholder="Seu nome" class="form-control requiredField" type="text" data-error-empty="Por favor entre com seu nome">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End name input -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="contact-mail">Email</label>
                            <div class=" controls">
                                <input id="contact-mail" name="email" placeholder="Seu email" class="form-control requiredField" type="email" data-error-empty="Por favor entre com seu email" data-error-invalid="Invalid email address">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End email input -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="contact-message">Mensagem</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <textarea id="contact-message" name="mensagem"  placeholder="Sua mensagem" class="form-control requiredField" rows="8" data-error-empty="Por favor entre com seu mensagem"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- End textarea -->
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcvSg8UAAAAAAsOYcKHl2mxO_Uq-e7e9X58sc_I"></div>
                        <p class="text-center"><button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-quattro" data-error-message="Error!" data-sending-message="Enviando..." data-ok-message="Mensagem Enviada"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><?= $modulo9->modulo9_button ?></button></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

                    </form><!-- End contact-form -->
                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
                        require_once  'sendmail.php';
                        if ($mail->Send()) {
                            echo "<p class='alert alert-success' id='msg_alert'> <strong>Obrigado !</strong> Seu e-mail foi entregue.</p>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<p class='alert alert-success' id='msg_alert'> <strong>Obrigado !</strong> Seu e-mail NÃO foi entregue.</p>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Agradeço desde já.

O erro agora é outro, a mensagem de erro é exibida o tempo todo, só desaparece quando o email é enviado, onde ela dá lugar a mensagem de sucesso no envio. É o único problema agora. Essa mensagem só precisa ficar oculta por padrão e exibir só quando o else for chamado, mas está exibindo o tempo todo.

O que estou utilizando é:

```
    <?php
    require_once  'sendmail.php';
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['email'])  && $mail->Send()) {
        echo "<p class='alert alert-success' id='msg_alert'> <strong>Obrigado !</strong> Seu e-mail foi entregue.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p class='alert alert-danger' id='msg_alert'> <strong>Email não enviado.</strong> Verifique o Captcha e os outros campos.</p>";
    }
?>
```

A biblioteca é o phpmailer

O sendmail.php:

```php
<?php
        require_once './loader.php';
        require_once './plugin/email/email.php';
        global $mail;
        $smtp = new Smtpr();
        $smtp->getSmtp();
        $mail->Port = $smtp->smtp_port;
        $mail->Host = $smtp->smtp_host;
        $mail->Username = $smtp->smtp_username;
        $mail->From = $smtp->smtp_username;
        $mail->Password = $smtp->smtp_password;
        $mail->FromName = $smtp->smtp_fromname;
        $mail->Subject = utf8_decode("Contato Via Site " . $site->site_meta_titulo);
        $mail->AddBCC($smtp->smtp_bcc);
        $mail->AddAddress($smtp->smtp_username);

        $data = date('d/m/Y H:i');
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

        $mail->AddReplyTo($email);
        $body = "<b>Data da Mensagem: </b> $data <br />";
        $body .= "<b>Nome:</b> $nome <br />";
        $body .= "<b>E-mail:</b> $email <br />";
        $body .= "<b>Mensagem: </b>$mensagem <br />";
        $mail->Body = nl2br($body);
        //$mail->Send();
    ?>
```

Comment: Quando o envio falha está mostrando mensagem de sucesso?  Ou não mostra nada? Presta atenção no texto exibido também, já que está utilizando a classe "alert-success" para a mensagem de falha.

Comment: Quando o envio falha, não mostra nada.

Comment: EU só mantive a classe alert-success pra testar se dessa maneira passaria a funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você diz que se o CAPTCHA não for preenchido a mensagem não deve ser enviada. Há um if externo que impede um tentativa de envio caso o campo não seja preenchido. Porem, não existe um `else` para este IF, e é ai que a mensagem de falha deveria ser mostrada. Você está mostrando esta mensagem apenas quando o CAPTCHA foi fornecido e houve um problema com o método `Send()`

Você pode remover o if interno e acrescentar `&& $mail->Send()` no final do IF externo, dessa forma:

```
    <?php
        require_once  'sendmail.php';
        if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['email'])  && $mail->Send()) {
            echo "<p class='alert alert-success' id='msg_alert'> <strong>Obrigado !</strong> Seu e-mail foi entregue.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p class='alert alert-success' id='msg_alert'> <strong>Obrigado !</strong> Seu e-mail NÃO foi entregue.</p>";
        }
    ?>
```

Lembrando que se uma das condições anteriores for falsa, o método `Send()` não será chamado.

Você também pode replicar o `else` do if interno, para o externo, mas pode ser um problema caso você queira mudar a mensagem e não lembre que ela está definida em dois locais.

Comment: Desta forma a mensagem de erro é exibida, todavia, a mensagem de sucesso parou de ser exibida e a página entra em um loading infinito após a tentativa de envio.

Comment: Não faz sentido, pois o código que postei faz exatamente o que o anterior fazia, só que utiliza o mesmo IF. Tem certeza que não houve algum problema com o envio do email. Loop infinito sem um for ou while não existe. Pode ser que teu script esteja esperando o servidor de envio responder.

Comment: E outro detalhe que acabei de perceber, a mensagem de erro é exibida o tempo todo.

Comment: Verifica se o envio está ocorrendo. Este código só vai exibir sucesso se todas as condições anteriores forem verdadeiras, e o retorno de  $mail->Send() também seja verdadeiro.

Comment: O email nã está sendo enviado.

Comment: Edita tua pergunta e posta o código, aqui fica ilegivel.

Comment: Consegui resolver parcialmente o problema. O arquivo sendmail estava com uma alteração que eu tinha feito e não tinha removido e por isso o carregamento infinito. O único problema agora é que antes de enviar o email, a mensagem de erro já aparece. de email não enviado.

Comment: A lógica que te passei está correta. Talvez você devesse olhar a documentação dessa lib que você está utilizando para enviar email. E verificar o retorno da função Send(). Minha solução foi dada com base no código que você colocou na pergunta. Não conheço essa biblioteca e problemas relacionadas com ela eu não sei solucionar.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada. Pois agora está funcionando corretamente, porém, a mensagem de erro de email não enviado aparece o tempo todo, como se o Else já fosse chamado antes mesmo de qualquer parte do formulário ser preenchida.

Answer (score 1):

O caso do else nao ser acionado seria pq o **$mail->Send()** não retorna false em caso de falha, sugiro q veja o resultado da função usando o **var_dump($mail->Send())**, como mostra na documentacão, http://php.net/var_dump a funcao vai ajudar a saber o verdadeiro retorno da função